# How to make autologin like facebook

Tags: php, authentication

How to make autologin like facebook, I mean when anyone clicks remember me. It will automatically redirect him to welcome page every time instead of login page. I am using core PHP.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at cookies and/or sessions

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the log in as a cookie. Here's a form as a base:

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="frmLogin">
    <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>    
    <div class="field-group">
        <div><label for="login">Username</label></div>
        <div><input name="member_name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_login"]; } ?>" class="input-field">
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div><label for="password">Password</label></div>
        <div><input name="member_password" type="password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_password"]; } ?>" class="input-field"> 
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?> />
        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-submit-button"></span></div>
    </div>       
</form>
```

Here is an example of the PHP code used to do this. Take inspiration from it, wouldn't use it because it is outdated now.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog_samples");
    $sql = "Select * from members where member_name = '" . $_POST["member_name"] . "' and member_password = '" . md5($_POST["member_password"]) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($user) {
            $_SESSION["member_id"]         = $user["member_id"];

            if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                setcookie ("member_login",$_POST["member_name"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                setcookie ("member_password",$_POST["member_password"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
            } else {
                if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
                    setcookie ("member_login","");
                }
                if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) {
                    setcookie ("member_password","");
                }
            }
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Login";
    }
    }
    ?>
```